# ¿Cómo saber si usuario leyó Email enviado en -Net Core 6 -c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Buen día.
Necesito capturar el momento en que el usuario abra un Email enviado desde una API creada en .NET CORE 6

Lo que hago es crear una imagen de 1 x 1 en la que en el tag src le envió la url de un servicio que captura el Guid del registro para marcarlo como abierto:

```
string mailTracker = $"<img src=\"{url}/"mark-email-as-opened/{guid}/image.png" alt=\"\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" />";
```

Para esto generé una función que reciba un Guid y guarde el log en base de datos así:

```
[HttpGet("mark-email-as-opened/{guid}/image.png")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MarkEmailAsOpened([FromRoute] Guid guid)
    {
        Response response = await _emailService.MarkEmailAsOpened(guid);

        if (response.IsSuccess)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, response);
        }

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, response);

    }
```

Pero los gestores de Email alteran el src por lo que nunca ejecuta el método

¿Qué otra alternativa existe para poder hacer seguimiento del Email?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esa falla de seguridad la solventaron cancelando la descarga de imagenes desde los correos, no se si te servirá para traquear

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿tienes un ejemplo de cómo se alteró un mail?